# Any support for matrix build

Tags: google-cloud-build

Recently research different build tools , GCP CloudBuild is one of the selection 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders

one of require is work loop an array list and write the function only once and run in parallel

however i did not find Cloudbuild mention any about matrix build

Function which provided by Jenkins Plugin  https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/

or Github Action https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run is not designed to work with Jenkins out of the box and the links you included  do not mention how to do this.

As indicated [1] the best product to integrate Jenkins inside Google Cloud is to use Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).

[1] https://cloud.google.com/jenkins

Comment: i am able to do this with jenkins plugin, however i think cloudbuild should be independent product

Comment: the way i did by jenkinspipilematrix {
                agent any
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'linux', 'windows', 'mac'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'BROWSER'
                        values 'firefox', 'chrome', 'safari', 'edge'
                    }
                }